# Get empty space in container

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get an empty (in example white) area in a container with Javascript?
Is there a ready jQuery function or something equal?

[image: screen]

I need the width, height, left and top position of the 'empty' white area in Javascript.

**http://jsfiddle.net/P4QHj/**

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="box-item a">A</div>
  <div class="box-item d">D</div>
  <div class="box-item e">E</div>
  <div class="box-item f">F</div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.box-item {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: grey;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
}

#container {
 position:relative;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 min-width:300px;
 max-width:300px;
}

.a {
 position:relative;
 left:100px;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}

.d {
 left:0px;
 top: 200px;    
}
.e {
 left:100px;
 top: 200px;    
}
.f {
 left:200px;
 top: 200px;    
}
```

​

TIA
frgtv10

Comment: What do you mean by empty space ? what do you actually want to get ?

Comment: What is this, please add more information, what is this?

Comment: What is "empty space" and what the "container" should be?

Comment: thanks for help. i added html + what i need to question.

Comment: You mean the white area?

Comment: can you provide a working jsFiddle example, please? this code doesn't seem to render the situation on the image

Comment: This is just a matter of some math. Find the space that is defined by the `.items`-divs and derive the remaining space from that. And I'm pretty sure thate there is not a *ready jquery function* for this.

Comment: @haynar I updated my question with jsfiddle link... http://jsfiddle.net/P4QHj/

Comment: @Yoshi can u help me with the math? Thats why I asked... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it's easy: You know the layout, take the `left` value of "A" and the `top` value of the other elements - `100 x 200px`.

For a more general solution with unknown space and unknown elements positions, you can only apply a grid/table on the container.

1. get dimensions of your `#container`
2. choose a grid spacing (in your case: `100px`, to get all space in unknown layouts use 1px)
3. Build a two-dimensional array  of the size "dimension" / "grid interval" (here: `3x3`) of boolean values or zeros
4. loop over all box-items

   1. get position and dimension of the box
   2. divide through grid interval
   3. increase the coverage count (or set to `true`) of the respective values in the array
5. The spaces still have `0`/`false` value in the grid. Multiply their indizes with the grid spacing to get the coordinates.

For getting dimensions, jQuery's [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)/[`height`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) functions can be of help. For the positions, you will need to read the `top`/`left` style values. They would be much easier to get when written as inline styles, not with ids (or even once-used classes) in a style sheet.

Comment: thanks for your help. i will use the dynamic general solution, because the grid is still different.

Answer (score 0):

This might be not exactly solution you are particularly looking for, but as it matches the title of this question, I think might be useful for some others searching for solution.

Assumptions:

1. container has size 3 x 3 cells
2. cells are same size
3. I refer to cells by column number than row (positioning first horizontally, then vertically)
4. you have an object that contains information about occupied spaces in container (lets call it  "occupancy").
   In my example each final entry holds an object having "width" property holding horizontal size of the content (I call them "tile"), but this might be also flat integer assigned directly to the entry.

Example content:

```
occupancy[0][1] = {width: 1};
occupancy[1][0] = {width: 1};
occupancy[1][1] = {width: 2};
occupancy[2][2] = {width: 1};
```

So it makes the occupancy look like ("x" means occupied):

```
| - | x | - |
| x | x | x |
| - | - | x |
```

Implementation:

```
const COLUMNS_COUNT = 3;
const MAX_ROWS = 3;
const tilesGroupedByRowColumn = {
    '0': {'1': {width: 1}},
    '1': {'0': {width: 1}},
    '1': {'1': {width: 2}},
    '2': {'2': {width: 1}},
}

let getTileOccupancyAreasMatrix = function () {

    let tileOccupancyAreasMatrix = {};

    for (let row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++) {
        for (let column = 0; column < COLUMNS_COUNT; column++) {
            if (typeof tileOccupancyAreasMatrix[row] === 'undefined') {
                tileOccupancyAreasMatrix[row] = {};
            }

            if (tileOccupancyAreasMatrix[row][column] === 1) {
                // columns have been marked used by some previous iteration,
                // that was handling tiles extending to more than 1 column width
                continue;
            }

            if (typeof tilesGroupedByRowColumn[row] === 'undefined'
                || typeof tilesGroupedByRowColumn[row][column] === 'undefined') {
                tileOccupancyAreasMatrix[row][column] = 0;
                continue;
            }

            let tileWidth = tilesGroupedByRowColumn[row][column].width;
            let tileHeight = tilesGroupedByRowColumn[row][column].height;
            // code below also handles the case when tile extends to next rows and column(s)
            for (let rowNumber = row; rowNumber < row + tileHeight; rowNumber++) {
                if (typeof tileOccupancyAreasMatrix[rowNumber] === 'undefined') {
                    tileOccupancyAreasMatrix[rowNumber] = {};
                }
                for (let columnNumber = column; columnNumber < column + tileWidth; columnNumber++) {
                    tileOccupancyAreasMatrix[rowNumber][columnNumber] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return tileOccupancyAreasMatrix;
},
```

Solution should work for any sizes of container - 3x3 example was given to make example simple.

Final solution probably should accept parameters than rely on predefined constants - my example comes from my Vue implementation, that reads off frameworks data, so no params were needed.